# Why is Jinput only getting one of two values from the url?

Tags: url, jinput

I am trying to extract two values from the url with Jinput.

My url is:

`http://localhost/kitchen-guide-new/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=45?subscribers_email=test@gmail.com&subscribers_name=test&encoding=UTF-8`

I am using the following code:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$name = $jinput->get('subscribers_name','none','raw');
$email = $jinput->get('subscribers_email','none','raw');

echo $name;
echo $email;
```

The problem is that I only get the last value; in other words I'm getting:

```
$name = 'test';
$email = 'none'; // (should be test@gmail.com)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how I should fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that second question mark, the link should be

`http://localhost/kitchen-guide-new/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=45&subscribers_email=test@gmail.com&subscribers_name=test&encoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

Your malformed url querystring is to blame -- specifically the second `?` which should be `&`.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/e5TYH):

```
$url = 'http://localhost/kitchen-guide-new/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=45?subscribers_email=test@gmail.com&subscribers_name=test&encoding=UTF-8';

parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $array);

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'option' => 'com_content',
  'view' => 'article',
  'id' => '45?subscribers_email=test@gmail.com',
  'subscribers_name' => 'test',
  'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
)
```

You see, the querystring parsing is dependent on the first occurring `?` to dictate the start of the data.  The key-value pairs are bound together with `=` and are separated from other pairs by `&`.

As a consequence of your typo, the `subscribers_email` key and value are appended to the `id` value.